# Using the Prolog select predicate?

Tags: select, recursion, prolog, logic, predicate

I'm trying to make a program where `seat(Guests, Seating)` holds if the people in the list Guests can be re-arranged into the list Seating so that each one is compatible to the ones on either side.

I have facts for each person:

```
topics(neil, [diving, football, computers, hockey]).
```

etc...

I also have a common predicate which is a rule that tests if two people have a common topic.

```
common(Person1, Person2, Topic)
```

I will have to use the built-in select predicate and my user defined common predicate but I'm not sure how.

Can someone provide a suitable solution or explanation please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have to have common topics between the first and last person of the Seating list, you can:

- Select one guest from the Guests, this will also get the Seating list without that selected guest
- Call a recursive procedure that takes that guest and selects another guest (again returning a lists of remaining Guests), and test for compatibility. If they are compatible the call recursively that procedure with the new guest.
- The base case of this procedure is when there are no more guests in the Guests list.

That would look something like:

```
seats(Guests, [Person1|Seating]):-
  select(Person1, Guests, NGuests),  
  seats1(Person1, NGuests, Seating).

seats1(_, [], []).
seats1(LPerson, Guests, [RPerson|Seating]):-
  select(RPerson, Guests, NGuests),
  common(LPerson, RPerson, _),  % There is a common topic between them
  seats1(RPerson, NGuests, Seating).
```

Comment: To clarify: the way that this works is that `select/3` will choose an element from the list (starting from the first), and if this path in the solution tree fails, on backtracking `select` will pick the next element from the list and the search for a solution will continue from there.

Comment: @Boris, correct!. `select/3`, as used here (with the first and third arguments uninstantiated and the second argument instantiated) will take one element from the list of the second argument (unifying it on the first argument) and unify the third argument with the remaining elements of the list. Upon backtracking it will test with every other element of the list (second argument of `select/3`). Of course you can also call seats with the second list instantiated to test if a Seating list is compatible with some Guests list